# Cant retrieve information from database using php

Tags: php, database

I have a very simple piece of code i cant get working. I am just trying to search these three tables for these values. When I remove the second two Select statements it works and no matter what table i choose from it works. It has something to do with the UNION statements.Thanks

```
$query =    "SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, yards FROM quarterbacks WHERE  Nickname='$nickname' AND Last_Name='$last_name'
            UNION 
            SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, yards FROM runningbacks WHERE Nickname='$nickname' AND Last_Name='$last_name'
            UNION 
            SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, yards FROM recievers WHERE Nickname='$nickname' AND Last_Name='$last_name'";

$result =mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('error getting data');
```

Comment: Are you sure those entries exist in your database?

Comment: please show us you table structure ..

Comment: Change this `AND Last_Name='$last_name` to `AND Last_Name='$last_name'` in first line.

Comment: print your query and execute it in database manually... n got error??

Comment: Yes sorry i did fix the ' but it is still not working

Comment: And yes they are for sure

Comment: Are there any errors showing?

Comment: Just a message i put in saying error getting data

Comment: Place your query in database. And, check manually what error coming. This is the best way to know the exact problem rather than searching here.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$query= "SELECT  quarterbacks.First_Name AS a, quarterbacks.Last_Name AS b, quarterbacks.yards AS c, runningbacks.First_Name AS p, runningbacks.Last_Name AS q, runningbacks.yards AS r, recievers.First_Name AS x, recievers.Last_Name AS y, recievers.yards AS z 
        FROM  quarterbacks, runningbacks, recievers 
        WHERE Nickname='$nickname' AND Last_Name='$last_name'";
```

Comment: I did! Same result! Thanks for the help though, i really appreciate it i've been stumped for a while!

Answer (score -1):

I think you have missed single quote

```
    SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, yards FROM quarterbacks WHERE       
Nickname='$nickname' AND Last_Name='$last_name

SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, yards FROM quarterbacks WHERE Nickname='$nickname' AND Last_Name='$last_name' -<<<<<<
```

Comment: it's ok run your first select in phpmyadmin does it return anything?

Comment: Big shoutout dude figured it out thanks to your help

Comment: what was the problem bro